# Is there a term|phrase for a grading assessment that counts the best m of n?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm assigning weights to different course assessments.

```
Assessment                    Weight
============================  ======
Assignments (best 5 of 8)       50%
Mid-term exam                   20%
Final exam                      30%
```

Is there a noun or noun-phrase for a grading scheme that counts the best m of n marks? Example: There are weekly assignments worth 10% each, the best 5 of 8 will be counted.

Comment: So you're asking for a word for a grading system where the maximum you can score would be 5 x 10%  = 50%?  *Unfair* would be one word, but I could think of several other less polite words!

Comment: @TrevorD, there are of course additional assessments that sum to 100%. As an exmaple: weekly assignments (best 5 of 8) 50%, mid-term 20%, final exam 30%.

Comment: This is similar to the concept of a [truncated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_mean) or modified mean, where the top and bottom scores are discarded and the rest are used to determine the actual score.

Comment: I would be helpful to add a sample sentence to your question, like "I grade weekly assignments using a ___" if you want a noun or noun phrase, or "I grade weekly assignments by ___" if you want a verb phrase.

Comment: @Nathaniel, thanks for the input. I've edited the question to try to clarify some.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your usage. I more often hear ***top 5*** rather than *best 5*, though. This [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=top%205%2C%20best%205&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctop%205%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbest%205%3B%2Cc0) agrees:

[image]